# Proof that uniform convergence allows the sum and integral signs to be exchanged

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, summation, contour-integration

On wikipedia, the proof that all holomorphic functions on some open subset of the complex plane are analytic on said subset contains the following step:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{1}{w-a}\cdot\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z-a}{w-a}\right)^nf(w)\,\mathrm{d}w=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w.$$
Basically, the sum and integral signs are interchanged, and it is justified in the proof by the fact that the sum is uniformly convergent on $C$. I understand this, but I want to see a proof that it implies that they can be interchanged, specifically in this case of a contour integral and a uniformly convergent sum. Do I need to know measure theory to understand how to prove this? All the results concerning the interchange of the sum and integral signs I have seen so far involve measure theory, which I am not at all familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

With the full force of uniform convergence, no, there is no technical difficulty, because if $f_n \to f$ uniformly then given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$:

$$\left |  \int f_n(x) dx - \int f(x) dx \right | \leq \int |f_n(x)-f(x)| dx \leq \int \varepsilon dx = \varepsilon L$$

where here $L$ is just the length of the path.

Part of the power of measure theory is not needing such a strong assumption as uniform convergence to justify interchanging limit and integration.